# Duplicate data in ListView?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` that fill from `Sqlite` . But when I fill the `ListView` I see Duplicate Data.

My `Struct.class` :

```
public class Struct{
    public String IdS;
    public String NameS;
    public String Group;
}
```

My `Activity.class` :

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new AdapterPSK(MPSK, activity, width, context);
        ListView lstPa = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstPasokhgoo);
        lstPa.setAdapter(adapter);

                Struct stp = new Struct();
                cursor_Sharee = sql.rawQuery("SELECT ID_P,Name_P,Group_P FROM ChatPasokhgo_tbl where Group_P = '" + "LOL" + "'", null);
                try {
                    if (cursor_Sharee != null) {
                        if (cursor_Sharee.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                stp.IdS = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("ID_P"));
                                stp.NameS = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("Name_P"));
                                stp.Group = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("Group_P"));
                                MPSK.add(stp);
                            } while (cursor_Sharee.moveToNext());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }finally{
                    cursor_Sharee.close();
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`MPSK` is:

```
public ArrayList<Struct> MPSK = new ArrayList<Struct>();
```

My `AdapterPSK.class` :

```
public class AdapterPSK extends ArrayAdapter<Struct> {
    static boolean enable = true;
    static Activity activity;
    static int widths;
    public AdapterPSK(ArrayList<Struct> array,Activity act,int WIDTH,Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.chat_page, array);
        activity = act;
        widths = WIDTH;
    }

        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
            layoutRoot = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutRoot);
            txtname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        }
        public void fill(ArrayAdapter<Struct> arrayAdapter,final Struct item , int position)
        {
            MarginLayoutParams txtN = (MarginLayoutParams) txtname.getLayoutParams();
            txtN.rightMargin = MarginRight;
            txtname.setTextSize(TextSize);

            if (item.NameS != null) {
                txtName.setText(item.NameS);
            }else if(item.NameE != null){
                txtName.setText(item.NameE);
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        Struct item = getItem(position);
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_pasokhgoo,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Notice : `ListView` show me last row of sqlite . But when I get `Log` see all of fetching data .My `Query` is true .  My bug is from MPSK .

Comment: what is MPSK in last line inside loop?

Comment: MPSK is:

public ArrayList<Struct> MPSK = new ArrayList<Struct>();

Comment: does your listview only show last row of your sqlite data?

Comment: If my sqlite has 2 row in listView show me 2 row but the data is value last row .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Struct stp = new Struct();` should be in :

```
  do {
        Struct stp = new Struct();
          .....
           ......

     } while (cursor_Sharee.moveToNext());
```

;)

Answer (score 1):

Clear MPSK after retrieving cursor.. as

```
     cursor_Sharee = sql.rawQuery("SELECT ID_P,Name_P,Group_P FROM ChatPasokhgo_tbl where Group_P = '" + "LOL" + "'", null);
    MPSK.clear();
try
{

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change this**

```
if (cursor_Sharee != null) {
                        if (cursor_Sharee.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                stp.IdS = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("ID_P"));
                                stp.NameS = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("Name_P"));
                                stp.Group = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("Group_P"));
                                MPSK.add(stp);
                            } while (cursor_Sharee.moveToNext());
                        }
```

**To**

```
 if (cursor_Sharee != null) 
{                       
      while(cursor_Sharee.moveToNext()) 
             {

 stp.IdS = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("ID_P"));
                                    stp.NameS = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("Name_P"));
                                    stp.Group = cursor_Sharee.getString(cursor_Sharee.getColumnIndex("Group_P"));
                                    MPSK.add(stp);

                                } 
                            }
```